# jquery validation working but the fform is not getting posted

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code, it seems its doing its work but some of the things are not working, i am trying to figure out why

```
$("#form").submit(function( e ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  e.preventDefault();
  const startDate = document.getElementById('stardate');
  const endDate = document.getElementById('enddate'); 
  if(startDate.length == 0 && endDate.length == 0){
    alert("hello");
    if (!validateDates(startDate.value, endDate.value)) {
            $("#div").empty().html('End date cannot be more than a year after start date');
        }
    }
  function validateDates(start, end) {
    const startDate = new Date(start);
    const endDate = new Date (end);
    // Create a comparison time 1 year prior to end date
    // Note there is a potential flaw if the end date is 29 February
    const dateCompare = new Date(
        endDate.getFullYear() - 1,
        endDate.getMonth(),
        endDate.getDate()
        );
    // If compare date is < startDate we have an invalid set of dates
    return dateCompare < startDate;
  }
});
```

1. now i am making a check if both the fields are empty, do a normal submit, but it just hangs in there and does nothing. no call
2. how can i make sure if the startdate is provided, it automatically take today as end date if user did not provided
3. and fail the validation if only enddate is provided and not start date

Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some comments along the way. It sounds like you want the form to submit normally under certain conditions, in which case you don't want to use e.preventDefault(). You can just `return false` instead. Also, I broke your validate function out of the submit() function. Also, I check for `field.value.length` rather than `field.length` which would always be greater than zero if you have the fields on the page...

```
$("#form").submit(function( e ) {
  // use e.preventDefault(); if you definitely do not want the form to submit like usual 
  // you can use return false to prevent the form from being submitted conditionally
  // e.preventDefault();
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  const startDate = document.getElementById('stardate');
  const endDate = document.getElementById('enddate'); 

  // check for value length rather than element length
  if(startDate.value.length == 0 && endDate.value.length == 0){
    // both fields are empty, allow the submit
    return true; // or whatever...
  } else {
    
    if (startDate.value && !endDate.value) endDate.value = new Date();
    else if (!startDate.value && endDate.value) return false;

    if (!validateDates(startDate.value, endDate.value)) {
            $("#div").empty().html('End date cannot be more than a year after start date');
            return false;
        }

    // if we get here, then everything passed validation and we can return true
     return true;
    }
  
});


function validateDates(start, end) {
    const startDate = new Date(start);
    const endDate = new Date (end);
    // Create a comparison time 1 year prior to end date
    // Note there is a potential flaw if the end date is 29 February
    const dateCompare = new Date(
        endDate.getFullYear() - 1,
        endDate.getMonth(),
        endDate.getDate()
        );
    // If compare date is < startDate we have an invalid set of dates
    return dateCompare < startDate;
  }
```